# running count in linq

Tags: linq-to-objects

I'm trying to figure out  if it's possible to do running totals in linq.  I'm going against a list, not to sql.  I've done running list in sql but can't find anything if you can do it in linq.

```
col1  col2  col3
1     a     afafaf
2     b     adfali
3     c     adfiaj
4     d     adfi
```

thanks
shannon

~~~~portion added below
I can't get the example you give transposed.. so i'll give a different example of what i'm trying to do.  I'm trying to go against a list(of JobS).  Jobs has instances of Job in it and Job has properties of Duties and Class in it.  So i'd like a linq statement with that in mind.   And if you know how to do it in vb... well i couldn't hardly ask for more.
Thanks
Shannon

Comment: Count of what? The number of elements inside the list?

Comment: no.. a running count where row 1 comes back as 1, row two comes back as 2.  The data in the running count doesn't reference any of the data in the list, just the line number for the row as it sits in the list..

Answer (score 2):

You can increment an indexer in a Select statement:

```
var data = new string[][]
{
    new string[] {"a", "afafaf"},
    new string[] {"b", "adfali"},
    new string[] {"c", "adfiaj"},
    new string[] {"d", "adfi"}
};

int rowCount = 1;
var table = data
   .Select(d => new { col1 = rowCount++, col2 = d[0], col3 = d[1] })
   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I understand you wrong, but from your description I think you may be interested in the `IndexOf` method. You pass the row value and it returns you the index/position of that row inside the list:

Sample:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> ints = new List<int>();

        ints.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1, 10));

        int index = ints.IndexOf(4);

        //Prints 3
        Console.WriteLine(index);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```